# Cannot move individual contacts among storage locations

Tags: contacts

I am on Samsung S10e, Android 12.
In my older phone/OS, I used to be able to move individual contacts among the various storage locations.
E.g., I could move a contact from my phone to my Google account (exception: once a contact was in Google, I couldn't move it elsewhere, but I guess that was normal).
Now I can't see that option anymore. The closest I found is with

*Contacts* -> *Three bars* -> *Manage contacts* -> *Move contacts*

but that seems to move all contacts in one location to another.

Can I recover the previous behavior?

Note: I don't want to sync contacts, but move among storage locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was only missing one step... entering *Move contacts*.

Still, I wonder why Samsung removed the capability for moving a contact from within the view of that contact, as it used to be possible, given it is a useful feature.

Comment: "*Still, I don't know why I cannot move a contact from within the view of that contact, as it used to be.*" this depends on the Contacts app, which is highly customizable by the vendor/ROM.

Comment: @AndrewT. - I rephrased my statement.